# Input type "range" - Set dynamic range

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to set the minimum value of a input of type `range` equal to the value of a specific field.

At this moment, I have this:

*These shown in a modal window*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="NumDevices" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="NumDevices" type="text" asp-for="NumDevices" class="form-control" />
        <input id="getNum" type="range" max="10" step="1" onchange="fetch()" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my current JS:

```
<script>
    function getminimun() { 
        var minimun = document.getElementById("NumDevices").value;
        var shareminimun = Number(minimun);
        document.getElementById("getNum").min = shareminimun;
    }
</script>
```

**Questions:**
I need to call my getminimun() function into my input of id: "getNum". How can I do that? Is there an onload option? onload="getminimun()"

Is it correct what I'm proposing? Can it be made better?

For any curious, this is my `fetch()` function:

```
<script>
    function fetch()
    {
        var get = document.getElementById("getNum").value;
        document.getElementById("NumDevices").value = get;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: just use the onchange event handler of the #NumDevices field

Comment: @JoshuaK Like: <input id="NumDevices" onchange="getminimun()" type="text" asp-for="NumDevices" class="form-control" />? It should not work on "onchange". Just need to set the minimum once the modal is load for one time only

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

Since I'm using a modal window to show these fields I added the following code in order to execute the Javascript once the modal opens.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function getminimun() {
        $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var minimun = document.getElementById("NumDevices").value;
            var shareminimun = Number(minimun);
            document.getElementById("getNum").min = shareminimun;
            document.getElementById("getNum").value = shareminimun;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It was also needed to set the value of the "getNum" input type range for this particular case.